# DJANGO DATATABLES template not working

Tags: python, django, datatables

i'm working on a simple example for using the datatables I fetch the result but the templates are not showing at all and there's no error in the console !
this is my html page : trial.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/jquery.dataTables.css" %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/dataTables.tableTools.css" %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}" type="text/javascript" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "js/jquery.dataTables.js" %}" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example">
     <thead>
         <tr><th></th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": {
                 "processing": true,
                 "url": "{% url 'url' %}",
                 "dataSrc": ""
             },
             tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
         } );
     } );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my simple view :

```
def myModel_asJson(request):
    object_list = list(Utilisateur.objects.values_list("Login"))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(object_list))
```

and the urls :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('SI.views',
                    url(regex=r'^',
                    view='myModel_asJson',
                    name='url'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('SI.views',
                    url(regex=r'^', 
                    view='myModel_asJson',
                    name='url'),
)
```

There are a few issues in your code: the JSON call is on the root (I think that's one of the issues) ! The view mixes up camel case and an underscore. The JSON call URL name is `url`. Apparently, you return user logins so better make your code explicit:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('SI.views',
    url(regex=r'^api/logins/', view='login_list', name='api-login-list'),
)
```

Change the view name as well of course. Then test it directly, go to `http://localhost/api/logins/` to see if you get the proper list. Ideally, you want a functional test for that.

Finally, just change this in your template:
"url": "{% url 'api_login_list' %}",

---

Also in your view:

```
object_list = list(Utilisateur.objects.values_list("Login"))
```

Shouldn't it be `login`? No uppercase.